# MYSQL question querying total number of hours worked by an administrator

Tags: mysql

The tables are the following;

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from AdmWorkHours;
+-------+------------+-------+
| empId | day        | hours |
+-------+------------+-------+
|    17 | 2021-08-15 |  4.00 |
|    17 | 2021-09-18 | 15.00 |
|    25 | 2021-08-17 |  8.00 |
|    38 | 2021-08-20 | 10.00 |
|    64 | 2021-08-31 |  7.50 |
+-------+------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from Administrator;
+-------+--------------+--------+
| empId | name         | gender |
+-------+--------------+--------+
|    17 | Rishabh Pant | M      |
|    25 | Mary Kom     | F      |
|    38 | Sarah Taylor | F      |
|    64 | Hasan Ali    | M      |
+-------+--------------+--------+
```

my query has to return the empId , names , and total working Hours for each administrator.

This has been the best query I have come up with my I cannot seem to get the total to sum up per admin.

```
select a.empId , a.name , sum(distinct h.hours) from Administrator AS a , AdmWorkHours AS h order by h.hours asc;
```

Comment: Don't ever use comma-separated joins. They are prone to errors (as you now see for yourself), which is why we have explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.) in the SQL standard since **1992**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a left join:

```sql
SELECT a.empId, a.name, COALESCE(SUM(a.hours), 0) AS hours_worked
FROM Administrator a
LEFT JOIN AdmWorkHours awh
    ON awh.empId = a.empId
GROUP BY a.empId, a.name;
```

The main problem with your current query is that you are doing a join without any condition, hence it defaults to being a cross join.  You are also using the old implicit join syntax.  Consider using my version above for best results here.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice this one

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the join condition and just need a group by:

```
select empId, name, sum(hours)
from Administrator natural join AdmWorkHours
group group by empId, name;
```

You can add the `coalesce()` that @TimBiegeleisen and left join if you want 0 for when admin had no hours.  My solution will just not show those records.

Comment: Allan Wind I appreciate your help very much! Thank you!

Comment: Will not show a row for an administrator who have no working time. So LEFT joining may be more safe.

Comment: A `NATURAL JOIN` is something you shouldn't use *ever*. Imagine some DBA decides to add a column `ID` or `INFO` or 'LAST_UPDATE` or the like to the tables. Then suddenly your queries don't work anymore, because these additional columns are considered in the join. Natural joins should never have been invented in my opinion.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner natural joins leads to cleaner queries so I use them whenever I can.  Even if you use explicit join conditions that does not protect you from changes.  For instance, let's say the dba decides to change the key name in both tables.  Your explicit join will now break but natural join would continue to work.  You may have standards, say, rails, that (mis)use id as primary key for every table, and tag on timestamps by by default.  This prevents the use of natural joins.

Comment: @manny make sure you accept the best answer so we know you are all set (and later you will be able also upvote answers that were helpful to you).

Comment: @Akina yes, I know, but I purposely provided a slightly different solution than TimBiegeleisen.   It's not clear to me which best answer the question.  In the data provided there is no difference in output.

Comment: @Allan Wind: If a DBA decided to change key column names, not only my queries, but also some of the DBA's body parts would break :D

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ;-)

Comment: Since I am still a beginner in MYSQL having seen both perspectives helps me better understand how the DBMS works. Thank you everyone!